# Is there a way to format a bash file to become a one liner?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash file that is pretty long, and I don't want to spend hours painstakingly going through and making it a one liner. Is there some online tool or command I can use to make my file into a one liner?

I already tried looking for beautifiers and formatters, but none do what I need it to, and I even searched on here for about an hour and all I could find was stuff about how to make a one liner not how to convert my entire file into a one liner.

Comment: What benefit is there in having it as a single line?

Comment: less file space

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: I edited my question to include that.

Comment: A `one-liner` may derive from `awk` scripts which performs versatile tasks with a simple
(mostly single) statement. Cramming long statements down into a single line will bring
no benefits at the sacrifice of readability and maintainability. We should not call it `one-liner`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for _practical_, answerable questions. Making your code unmaintainably short is impractical by nature. (And not all changes that can be needed to accomplish this are easy to do automatically; heredocs, f/e, throw a wrench in the works of the usually easy approach).

Comment: `less file space` do you want to make it specifically more concise, or make it one line?

Comment: If disk space is a concern, gzip the script and execute with `zcat script.gz | bash`

Comment: Readability and Maintainability far outweigh having it as a one-liner -- not worth the trouble. (unless you are participating in a script obfuscation contest)

Comment: Disk space is cheap.

Comment: You are unlikely to save much space by putting everything on one line.  Many newlines will have to be replaced by semicolons.  You'll also reduce readability, and maintainability.  However, there are some cases where it is useful to convert multiple lines of code to a single line.  One such case is when you want to put code in a comment like this!

Comment: If the code doesn't contain constructs that make it impossible do join lines (e.g. comments, here documents) I think there is a way to do what you want using standard Bash features (not a special tool or library).  I can't put it in an answer since the question has been closed.  I've voted to reopen the question.

Comment: @pjh, are you thinking about collapsing runs of newlines down to a single newline, and then replacing newlines with semicolons? It would take some care to make that work everywhere -- lines ending with `&`, f/e, won't behave well under the circumstance (`&;` being invalid syntax). Moreover, as I understand it the reason the OP isn't doing this by hand is that their code is too large, which presumably makes it also too large to comfortably hand-audit for unworkable constructs.

Comment: There are two main reasons for this. Number one is disc space which is not that big of a deal, and number two is to speed up a read program. I have a seperate program to read and index each function of my script and if I make the script that needs to be indexed, It would save me a lot of lines for the indexing script and it would run faster in general.

Comment: I don't see how it would make the indexing script faster to compress everything on one line. Parsing `line1;line2` isn't any easier than `line1<newline>line2`, and parsing `funcname() { funcline1; funcline2; };` isn't any easier than parsing `funcname() {`, `funcline1`, `funcline2` and `}` on separate lines.

Comment: I am writing the indexing script in Nasm and to process a new line (0x0a), makes it take longer.

Comment: You may be able to use the Bash [history](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-History-Facilities) mechanism to do what you want.  Commands that have been run are usually converted to single lines when they are saved in the history.  That includes lengthy compound commands, like `(...)`.

Comment: One possible way to do what you want is to temporarily modify the file that contains the code you want to convert to a one-liner.  Before the code put `set -o history` (history is not enabled by default in non-interactive shells).  Then put  `(` on a line by itself.  After the code put `)` on a line by itself and then a `history` command.  If you then run the file the output should include a one-line version of the code, surrounded by `(` and `)`; which can easily be removed.  Comments in the original code are removed.  This doesn't work for code that includes here documents, at least.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, my idea is actually to use the Bash history mechanism to do the one-lining.  See my two recent comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a horrible idea. Do not do it.

That said, if you define the following function:

```
onelineify() {
  script_content=$(gzip -9 <"$1" | base64 -w0)
  printf '%s\n' '#!/usr/bin/env bash'
  printf 'eval "$(base64 -d <<<%q | gunzip -c)"\n' "$script_content"
}
```

`onelineify yourscript` will write a version of your script that is only one line (beyond the shebang) to stdout.

Comment: Jinx. My suggestion was going to be `printf '%s\n' "#!/bin/bash" "eval \"\$(base64 -d <<< $(cat myscript | gzip -9 | base64 | tr -d '\n')|gzip -d)\""` which also compresses since file size appeared to be an issue

Comment: Fair point; might as well add that here.

Comment: I got a bunch of gibberish when I did that. And when I ran the gibberish, I got no output.

Comment: This is the closest thing to an actual answer and not people telling me not to do it, so I up-voted, but I will not accept it as it did not work for me. Thank you!

Comment: @TryToDoIt, gibberish is what it's supposed to be. As for the trying to run it, run `bash -x yourscript`, where `yourscript` is the gibberish, and see what it spits out.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This did give me an output but it just gives me syntax errors that do not occur when I run the script without it being "onelineified".

Comment: @TryToDoIt, I'd need to see the specific sample input for which you get syntax errors to comment further.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sadly it is too long and stack overflow wont let me comment it, Thank you for the help and actually answering my question.

Comment: Consider using an online sandbox like http://repl.it/ to add a reproducer. I'll put together a quick example repl there that shows this working, and then you can fork it to add more code to show a failure.

Comment: @TryToDoIt Here you are: https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/LongOrganicCodegeneration#main.sh

Comment: @TryToDoIt, ...the one thing I do ask is that you test that your `input-script.sh` works in the repl environment _before_ being one-lineified. If more software needs to be installed in the REPL, you can make that happen by editing the (hidden by default) `replit.nix` file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It does work in an environment and it does produce the expected output.

Comment: To be clear, by "the repl environment", I was talking about the http://repl.it/ environment _specifically_, not your own environment that nobody else can see. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244407/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-trytodoit).